# Phone will no longer connect via USB after bad ROM

Tags: recovery-mode, rom

I have a phone that was flashed with a bad ROM. It no longer has a system, so actually getting into the phone is a no-go. It can, however, boot into recovery and download mode. I planned on flashing to a stock ROM, but I can no longer connect via USB: Windows simply cannot recognize the device.

I've gone through various driver installations, but to no avail. I figured I'd give up on the USB and just put a stock ROM on an SDcard and install it through recovery. Would this work, or do I need to do it through USB?

Comment: You can flash a ROM through recovery from the SD card, but you can't (usually, depends on the device) go back to full stock as the full stock image (usually) includes recovery etc. Should be no issue to flash a ROM at least, then worry about going back to stock from there.

Comment: @RossC Awesome, that's what I wanted to hear. So I'd flash the stock ROM, get USB working again, and then flash again to ensure that the phone as both a stock ROM and stock recovery.

Comment: @Izzy done now, Liffer nope, flash a custom ROM to get it booting, then worry about getting back to stock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these things there are always exceptions and a few clever work-arounds, the below is general advice.

**Only flash a ROM for your exact device model**

You can't flash something not 'stock' through the stock recovery, attempting to do so will cause signature errors. The opposite; flashing stock ROM through a custom [recovery](/questions/tagged/recovery) will also error. So you will not be able to restore to stock first (more than likely anyway.)

However, since you don't immediately **need** the phone on stock, then you can copy any ROM compatible with your device onto the SD card and flash that through recovery. At least then you will be have a booting device, and can deal with the USB drivers issue.

Installing in recovery would usually involve the 2 main steps below:

`Wipe the device`
`Install from zip`

And then install any other zips you may need (e.g. [google-apps](/questions/tagged/google-apps)).

You could attempt to mount the SD card in your recovery but I'd guess you've tried all those options.

Also as Izzy has pointed out you may need a new [radio-firmware](/questions/tagged/radio-firmware) flashed on the device to allow "low level interface" connection, so the kernel has nothing to connect to.

**Once again ONLY flash something for your EXACT device or you will have a shiny paper weight!**

Comment: I was able to install [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1363071) custom ROM, but I still cannot connect via USB. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/w6zKnti.png) is a screenshot of the device info. I think this issue is at the kernel level, as the phone simply cannot supply information to the computer. Perhaps you can point me to some compatible kernel?

Comment: You could try this one (at your own risk of course): http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2217686 Have you tried a different cable, USB port, computer etc first? Worth a try.

Comment: I gave it a try, but no go. I've tried a couple of different ROMS, but nothing is getting the computer to recognize the phone. I've tried Kies and various other drivers, as well as different USB port and cables. At this point, I don't think it's worth the frustration. I may consider selling it for parts, which would be a shame since it's in like-new condition. I'll take this as a lesson.

Comment: "flashed with a bad ROM" (from your question) might have included a bad [radio-firmware](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/radio-firmware/info) – which would explain why it doesn't work with "any ROM tried": if the (wrong) radio doesn't supply the "low-level interface", there's nothing kernel or driver can plug in to. In this case, it might help finding a working (and up-to-date) radio image *for your device*, and flash that.

Comment: @Izzy great point, I've added a note to the and of the answer (crediting you).

Comment: Good idea, @RossC! You might wish to include the `[tag:radio-firmware]` (or the direct link to its tag-wiki, which might be preferable) for details on what that is and what to take care for. With the radio it's even more important to not flash any incompatible image: if that's broken, it might not be as easily re-flashed as a "normal ROM".